# Assigning returned JSON to global variable in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

This is my code:

```
var accountStatus;

function getAccountStatus()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/getAccountStatusJSON.php",
        async: false,
        data: "id_alumno=1",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (account)
        {
            console.dir(account);
            accountStatus= account;
            console.dir(accountStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the output of these console.dir lines:
(Apparently I can't use images so I'll have to write it out.)

---

CHROME:

Object

adeudo: "840"

descuento: "0"

total: "840"

[object Object]

---

FIREFOX:

adeudo: "840"

descuento: "0"

total: "840"

adeudo: "840"

descuento: "0"

total: "840"

---

So the JSON object does get copied into the global variable in firefox, but in **chrome** I can't use the JSON as a global variable, if I try to print for example: **accountStatus.total** I get **"undefined"** as the value.
What am I missing?

This is the full response:
**{"id_cuenta":"79","subtotal":"840","descuento":"0","total":"840","pagado":"0","adeudo":"840","fecha":"2014-09-10"}**

Comment: why are you doing `status = account`? don't you want to set `accountStatus = account`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron?newsletter=1&nlcode=97716%7c4ba7

Comment: Can you include the original JSON response? The value of any properties will depend on that and it may consist of multiple objects. So, the root object may not have a `total` property, but the objects it contains might. E.g.: `accountStatus[0].total`. [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Yup yup, sorry, I edited it. I had to modify the code a bit to keep it simple for the question.

Comment: Where/how are you trying to use the global variable?

Comment: Several times on different functions.

Comment: Keep in mind that `accountStatus` is not populated until the Ajax success callback is executed. Executing any other functions that need to access `accountStatus` before that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `accountStatus` is being used. I would change that to `status`.

Comment: No, `window.status` is an existing global variable, which is not writeable. This would lead to other problems.